# Skinny Controllers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to improve my Laravel code design by moving code away from the controllers as much as possible.

In my `AuthController` I have a `store` function for logging in the user, where can I move the logic in this function?

So far I have implemented a `FormRequest` for validation and `UserResource` for the response fields. I was thinking of creating a file in `/Services` called `AuthService` and moving authentication logic there, unless there is a better design pattern? Or maybe logic for authentication can be moved to the `User`'s model?

```
public function store(StoreAuthRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();

    if(!$user || !Hash::check($request->input('password'), $user->password)) {
        return response([
            'message' => 'Bad credentials'
        ], 401);
    }

    $token = $user->createToken('AppToken')->plainTextToken;

    return response([
        'user' => new UserResource($user),
        'token' => $token
    ], 201);
}
```

Comment: better not moving any of your system logic into model , you have other option class for that for example service class (multiple) or action class (singleton)

Comment: by the way if already sterilised your request using StoreAuthRequest, best not using $request->input again, instead use $request->validated() or $request->safe()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to never mixup what a "service" is/means. In Laravel a `Service` (not a `ServiceProvider`, but a literal folder called `Services` in the `app` folder) is a class that allows the developer to communicate with external services, it is not a "logic" class that drives something, like logic for logging in.

What I have done, after working so many years with Laravel, is to "mix" a little bit of DDD (Domain Driven Development), what I have done is just add a `Domain` folder inside `app`, and you put ALL your logic in there.

For example, imagine we have a Doctors app, this would be the heriarchy:

- app

  - Console
  - Domain
  - Exceptions
  - Http
  - Models
  - Providers
- bootstrap
- config
- database
- resources
- etc.

So, intead of having stuff inside a `app/Services`, just put code inside `Domain`, like this (following our example):

- Domain

  - Common (`App\Domain\Common`)

    - Enums
    - Events
    - Listeners
    - Jobs
    - Servicies
  - Doctor (`App\Domain\Doctor`)
  - Facility (`App\Domain\Facility`)
  - Patient (`App\Domain\Patient`)

So, the idea is to put true logic inside this `Domain` folder (and further organize them), so you can then NOT mix logic or stuff togheter.

To wrap it up, you would then have controllers like this:

```php
class PatientController extends Controller
{
    public function store(PatientRequest $request)
    {
        return \App\Domain\Patient\Entity::store(
            $request->input('name'),
            $request->input('email'),
            $request->input('age')
        );
    }
}
```

All the logic for "registering" (manipulating something from the Patient) model, is on the `Entity` class.

---

I have also taken a different approach by following something similar to having "modules", so everything is in a "modules" folder and that logic is just in there. I got that idea from [Ryuta Hamasaki: Modularising the Monolith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Rq-yHAwYjQ&t=4013s), but this may be way more advance.

Answer (score -2):

You can write the validator directly in the controller. Because this line of code has no possibility of being reused.

Example:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required'],
    ]);
    $user = User::query()
        ->where('email', $request->email)
        ->first();
    // PHP 8.x
    if (! Hash::check($request->password, $user?->password)) {
        // Throw an exception
    }
    
    return response()->json([
        'token' => $user->createToken(...)->plainTextToken,
        'user' => new UserResource($user), // or UserResource::make($user)
    ])
}
```

End.

Comment: I think you're going in the *opposite* direction OP wanted. Moving the validation *into* the controller makes a *thicker* controller.

Comment: @ceejayoz In general, it is recommended to put the validator in the Request. But too much encapsulation in the login scenario will make the code more difficult to understand